# React Native - create top bar modal that allows interaction outside of content

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, react-modal

In React Native, how can I create a React Modal that allows the user to still interact with the rest of the items that it does not cover when it is opened?
Just like in Whatsapp, when you select a message, a top bar would appear with different button actions, and the user is still able to scroll and select other messages, only when the user presses the back button, the bar modal closes. How to implement this functionality? Is that even a modal, or is that another component?